# System environment properties overriding spring boot application.properties

Tags: java, spring, macos, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In a spring boot application, I have a property in application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://host1:3306/test?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true
```

However when I start the application, it is connecting to a totally different database.

So when I checked the env values in /actuator/env it url, it shows that the value is getting overrided by an environment property

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL": {
          "value": "jdbc:mysql://host2:3306/test",
          "origin": "System Environment Property \"SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL\""
}
```

I have no idea where this environment property is configured.
I just want it to pick from my property file and not the environment. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: It comes from your system check for a `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` somewhere in your global exports and remove it.

Comment: What system are you using, Linux or Windows? You can always override the OS settings by Java System command line argument `-Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host1:3306/test?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true`. More details about precedence is here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Comment: I use mac. Problem is I checked in many of the places a global property can be set. And I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: @Michal this is just one example I have given of a property that is getting overriden. There are many other properties that are overriden in the same manner too in my application. So manually specifying each of them would be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

there are 17 ways to set and override properties in spring boot and they are ordered,
for example- application.properties outside the jar comes before application.properties inside the jar.

you could search potential source that override your properties in all those ways-
(ordered from strongest to weakest ) - copied from spring boot reference -https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

Devtools global settings properties in the $HOME/.config/spring-boot directory when devtools is active.

@TestPropertySource annotations on your tests.

properties attribute on your tests. Available on @SpringBootTest and the test annotations for testing a particular slice of your application.

Command line arguments.

Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property).

ServletConfig init parameters.

ServletContext init parameters.

JNDI attributes from java:comp/env.

Java System properties (System.getProperties()).

OS environment variables.

A RandomValuePropertySource that has properties only in random.*.

Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).

Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).

Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).

Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).

@PropertySource annotations on your @Configuration classes. Please note that such property sources are not added to the Environment until the application context is being refreshed. This is too late to configure certain properties such as logging.* and spring.main.* which are read before refresh begins.

Default properties (specified by setting SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties).